# How to resolve difference between bootRun and actually running the jar?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have a springboot application that starts up fine when I run `bootRun` from the gradle plugins in my IDE. However when I run `bootJar` and then run `java -jar myjar.jar` I am getting unsatisfied dependency errors. It seems wierd to me that `bootRun` would start it up fine but `bootJar` is not making the same package that is done when `bootRun` is run. I think it all is rooted with this error:

> Error creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration'

The reason I say this is that when I add

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration
```

to the appliation.yaml and rebuild the jar does actually startup without the UnsatisifiedDependencyExceptions. However the endpoints of the app return 404, likt they haven't been initialized by spring.

Does anybody know why this might happen? Here is my gradle file. If anybody has an idea how I can run the jar file as if I was running `bootRun` I would really like to hear how to do that. Thanks!

```
def props = new Properties()
file("gradle.properties").withInputStream { props.load(it) }

def build_username= props.getProperty("build_username")
def build_password= props.getProperty("build_password")


buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/gradle-plugins"
            credentials {
                username = build_username
                password = build_password
            }
            metadataSources {
                mavenPom()
                artifact()
            }
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/libs-release/"
            credentials {
                username = build_username
                password = build_password
            }
            metadataSources {
                mavenPom()
                artifact()
            }
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/plugins-release/"
            credentials {
                username = build_username
                password = build_password
                //            System.out.println("** GRADLEW_USERNAME ** ")
//            System.out.println(username)
//            System.out.println(password)
            }
            metadataSources {
                mavenPom()
                artifact()
            }
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/gradle-plugins-cache"
            credentials {
                username = build_username
                password = build_password
            }
            metadataSources {
                mavenPom()
                artifact()
            }
        }

        maven {
            url "https://maven.artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot/"
            credentials {
                username = build_username
                password = build_password
            }
            metadataSources {
                mavenPom()
                artifact()
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com-platform:mack-interceptor:0.1.2'
            classpath 'com.mycompany.sa.xc.ps.models:ps-custinfo:v2.0.5'
            classpath 'com.mycompany.finance.common:hdw2f-common-library:0.1.0+134-SNAPSHOT'
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
            classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.24.16"
            classpath 'com.adarshr:gradle-test-logger-plugin:3.0.0'
            classpath 'com.github.dreamhead:moco-runner:1.2.0'
            classpath 'com.github.node-gradle.node:com.github.node-gradle.node.gradle.plugin:7.0.1'
            classpath 'io.spring.dependency-management:io.spring.dependency-management.gradle.plugin:1.1.4'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.github.node-gradle.node'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'application'


repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/gradle-plugins"
        credentials {
            username = build_username
            password = build_password
        }
        metadataSources {
            mavenPom()
            artifact()
        }
    }
    maven {
        url "https://maven.artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/libs-release/"
        credentials {
            username = build_username
            password = build_password
        }
        metadataSources {
            mavenPom()
            artifact()
        }
    }
    maven {
        url "https://maven.artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/plugins-release/"
        credentials {
            username = build_username
            password = build_password
            //            System.out.println("** GRADLEW_USERNAME ** ")
//            System.out.println(username)
//            System.out.println(password)
        }
        metadataSources {
            mavenPom()
            artifact()
        }
    }
    maven {
        url "https://maven.artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/gradle-plugins-cache"
        credentials {
            username = build_username
            password = build_password
        }
        metadataSources {
            mavenPom()
            artifact()
        }
    }

    maven {
        url "https://maven.artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot"
        credentials {
            username = build_username
            password = build_password
        }
        metadataSources {
            mavenPom()
            artifact()
        }
    }

    maven {
        url "https://maven.artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/spring-milestone-cache"
        credentials {
            username = build_username
            password = build_password
        }
        metadataSources {
            mavenPom()
            artifact()
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        ext {
            springBootVersion = '2.3.1.RELEASE'
        }
        implementation 'com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:1.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
        implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'

        implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.7'

        implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}"
        implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml'
        implementation 'com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core'
        // Base Security Classes
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
        //implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config'
        // Needed for OIDC Login Process
        implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client"
        // Needed for Auth Code Processing
        implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose"
        implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'

        // Minimal Additional items beyond starter for resource server side.
        // https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-minimaldependencies
        implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server"
        implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2:2.2.5.RELEASE"

        // Lombok
        implementation group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.24'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'

        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup
        implementation group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.13.1'
        implementation 'org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:5.10.0.202012080955-r'

        // implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2'
        implementation('org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:1.3.8')

        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-storage
        // Azure Libraries
        implementation group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-storage', version: '8.6.6'
        implementation 'com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-mediaservices:1.1.0-beta.2'
        implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-identity', version: '1.4.0'
        implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-storage-blob', version: '12.14.1'
        implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-core', version: '1.21.0'
        implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-core-management', version: '1.2.1'
        implementation group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.15'
        implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-core-management', version: '1.4.1'
        implementation 'com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-videoanalyzer:1.0.0-beta.1'
        implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-messaging-eventhubs-checkpointstore-blob', version: '1.10.2'
        implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-messaging-eventhubs', version: '5.10.3'
        implementation group: 'io.projectreactor.netty', name: 'reactor-netty', version: '1.0.13'
        implementation group: 'io.projectreactor', name: 'reactor-core', version: '3.4.0'
        runtimeOnly group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt-jackson', version: '0.10.5'
        implementation group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt-api', version: '0.10.5'
        implementation group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-media', version: '0.9.8'

        testImplementation 'junit:junit'
        testImplementation 'org.easymock:easymock:3.6'
        testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock:1.6.4'
        testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.4'
        testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.4'
        testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-easymock-release-full:1.6.4'
        testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
        testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.2'

    }
}

//mainClassName = 'com.mycompany.hr.pocketguide.Application'
tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
//
node {
    download = false
    version = '16.0.0'
    download = true
    //workDir = file('${project.projectDir}/nodejs')
}

npm_run_build {
    args = ['run', 'build']
    dependsOn npmInstall

    inputs.files(fileTree('node_modules'))
    inputs.files(fileTree('src/main/js'))
    inputs.files(fileTree('src/main/resources/static'))
    inputs.file('package.json')
    inputs.file('webpack.config.js')
    outputs.dir('$buildDir/resources/main/static')
}

mainClassName = 'com.mycompany.hr.pocketguide.Application'
```

Comment: I solved this. The problem was that one of the beans that it was trying to autowire had a name that was conflicting with something else. I simply changed the name of the class and then it worked. Multiple DependencyNotSatisfiedExceptions were then solved.